# Can we track each audience's actions' duration on a webpage?

Tags: google-analytics, popup, time-tracking

I have a webpage consisting of a modal popup that would show up on click. I want to give the link to several audiences, and track each audience's duration when opening the open button until they finally click the close button.

How do we track the duration?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer how to post a good question in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is appreciable to try something in this front at first and then raise the question. For example a webpage can be developed in any technology like angular or react or simple JAM stack. Without knowing details no one can answer this question in an effective manner. Kindly reconsider posting a detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

You must track an event to be sent to Google Analytics when the user clicks on the buttons (both on Open and Close).

Time is calculated by Analytics for the difference between the first and last interaction.